# Yarn add lodash is causing a lodash require error in another module

Tags: npm-install, yarnpkg

I have a react native project that already requires and has installed `redux-actions`.

The app was working correctly.

I then added `yarn add lodash`

Afterwards I get an error

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'node_modules/redux-actions/node_modules/lodash/identity.js'`

Did yarn add remove the lodash somehow from redux-actions/node_modules?

How do I correct this error?

Now that I did an npm list I see that there is a lodash 3.10.1 installed and that redux-actions requires lodash@4.17.4.  Did yarn install that lodash based on a requirement of another module and hoiseted it into the root of node_modules?  How do I know which module caused that - I'd like to upgrade it to the latest lodash and want to make sure that doesn't break any dependencies.